# Storing values in simple array map

Tags: java, android

I have two loops, in first `for` loop I have headings and in second loop I have items related to those headings. Now My problem is storing those heading as well as items in simple array map.

Ex:

1. `heading1 = {item1,item2,item3, and so on}`
2. `heading2 = {item8,item10,and so on}`

How to achieve this type of storage in simple array map.

```
    for (int k = 0; k < checklistMainItems.size(); k++) {

         mainSub = checklistMainItems.get(k).getMainItemDescription().toString();

        for (int j = 0; j < checklistSubItems.size(); j++) {
            subItemTexts.add(checklistSubItems.get(j).getSubItemDescription().toString();}

        }
    }
```

Comment: how are you getting  checklistSubItems?

Comment: `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `HashMap` where key type you can have as `String` and value as `ArrayList` of Strings.

But if you want to use arrays then you can use `String map[][] = new String[checklistMainItems.size()][];` then inside the second loop you can put values in `map[k][j]`